# Delete content : file1.csv - file2.csv powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, text

I would like to do delete identic line between two differents .csv files.

Ex:

```
File1.csv                     File2.csv
Name,Age                      Name,Age
John,23                       John,23
Abdel,52                      Momo,58
Momo,58
Claire,91
```

Result would be:

```
Result.csv
Name,Age
Abdel,52
Claire,91
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-Csv -Path File1.csv, File2.csv | Group-Object -Property cid, Title| ? count -EQ 1 | % group | Export-Csv -Path Result.csv
```

Would do the trick

Answer (score 0):

@Joakim might have handled this for you already:
http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/An_Advanced_Cmdlet_to_Merge_Csv_Files_in_PowerShell

That would merge data based on one header.